# Associate two items of list/dict in Python (change the value of one would modify the other)

Tags: python, list, pointers, dictionary

In Python, is it possible to associate two items in a list/dict so that value changes of one would trigger the modification of the other?

For example, I have a list:

```
# Python example
# item_one = 'item_one'
# item_two = 'item_one'
list_with_associated_items = [item_one, item_two]
list_with_associated_items[0] = 'item_two'
# that's it, the value of list_with_associated_items[1] should turn to
# 'item_two' now.
```

So, what does the structure of the list/dict need to be to make the value of list_with_associated_items[1] turn into 'item_two' as well?

I can use pointers in C language to achieve such a goal, like:

```
/* C example */
char buffer[40] = 'associated_item';
char *item_one_pointer = buffer;
char *item_two_pointer = buffer;
char *associated_list[2] = [item_one_pointer, item_two_pointer];
/* Change the content of item one */
strcpy(associated_list[0], 'item_one');
printf('%s\n', associated_list[1]);
/* The printing result will be 'item_one', which means the second
   item has been modified because it is "associated" with item
   one (sharing the same memory) */
```

Are there similar techniques in Python? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could create your own subclass of `list` and use that instead.

Comment: You are operating over string literals. Which are immutable.

Comment: @zondo, would you mind give an simple example on using subclass of list? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `class mylist(list):` would of course be the first line because you want to inherit from `list`.  Then you need to change the `__setitem__` method to something like `def __setitem__(self, index, item):` `list.__setitem__(self, index, item)` `if index == 0: list.__setitem__(self, 1, item)`.  I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have two (or more) variable names bound to the same object.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = A
B[1] = 42
print(A)           # prints: [1,42,3]

C = [A, B]
C[0][1] = 9
print(A, B)        # prints: [1,9,3] [1,9,3]
print(C[0], C[1])  # prints: [1,9,3] [1,9,3]
```

As long as A, B, C[0], and C[1] are all bound (think pointing to) the same list.  Changing the list elements changes it for all bindings.

However: `B = ['a', 'b']` binds B to a new list. It does not change the old list. So:

```
B = ['a', 'b']
print(A, B)        # prints: [1,9,3] ['a','b']
```

It's kind of like the difference between these two C statements:

```
item_two_pointer[1] = 'Z';
item_two_pointer = another_buffer;
```